# Alternative of Matlab's Neural Network Toolbox in R

Tags: r, matlab, package, neural-network

Is there a kind of package in R for this? Is the "AMORE" package a possible surrogate for Matlab's Neural Network Toolbox? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, don't use NNs -- this is a junky and obsolete technology.

Comment: @mbq: Some people even still use the laws of Newton, imagine. Like that's ever going to hold a modern bridge together.

Comment: @Joris Newton laws are not obsolete; they work very well in a moderate scale, so they are still in use. NNs are not well defined, slower and usually less accurate then competitors.

Comment: @mbq: By constructing your layers correctly, you can create competitors in a neural network. I'm not sure if I understand you right...

Comment: @Joris I meant other classifiers there.

Comment: @mbq: I see :-) Yet a whole lot of technology based on neural networks still performs very well. They're not the one-thing-fits-all and maybe not the best classifier solution, but they do serve their purposes. In some cases, being not well defined is actually an advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the <s>library</s> **package**`nnet` offers a lot of functionality for neural networks. Alternatively, there is also `neural` for MLP and RBF networks. See also www.rseek.org

edit : for multilayer networks, AMORE is the way to go.

Comment: cough... "package" ...cough... ;-)

Comment: @ucfagls : cat(replicate(1000,"I will never call a package library again.\n"))

Comment: Joris gets an honorary Martin Maechler award for that.

Comment: @Dirk: a clear case of fortune("library"). Thx for the award ;-)

Comment: @Joris: thanks, I'm still studying neural network, and found that nnet only support single hidden layer, will it be a big issue? Actually I am trying to do some forecasting in stock price, and saw someone using Matlab, so wondering if R can also do similar stuff.

Comment: @lokheart: true. Didn't know you wanted multilayer networks specifically. For that, you'll need indeed amore, but I have no experience with that package.